# Using VLOOKUP and IMPORTRANGE to find a match and return one of two potential values

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, vlookup

I am trying to change the value of cell B1 depending on if cell A1's value is found in another spreadsheet. If there is a match, I want the cell to say "banned". If A1 isn't found in the other spreadsheet, I want it to say "active'.

I've been playing around with this

=if((VLOOKUP(A3,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/xyz","ALL BANNED ACCOUNTS!$G$2:$G$300"),1,false))=A3,"Banned","Active")

and can only get it to return "Banned". If there is no match, it always returns #N/A.

How can I remedy this?

Thanks!

Comment: could you specify how this would work?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing "FALSE" TO "TRUE". I have found that VLOOKUP behaves erratically, and simply changing the [is_sorted] value helps.

Also, this may or may not make a difference, but you have an extra set of parentheses in your formula:

```
=if(VLOOKUP(A3,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/xyz","ALL BANNED 
ACCOUNTS!$G$2:$G$300"),1,false)=A3,"Banned","Active")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but in case it helps someone, since you are using VLOOKUP in one column, the only choices are that it equals A3, or that it isn't found, and if it isn't found, VLOOKUP fails, rather than equaling something else. Therefore, you can use this formula:

```
=iferror(if(VLOOKUP(A3,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/xyz","ALL BANNED 
ACCOUNTS!$G$2:$G$300"),1,false)=A3,"Banned","irrelevant"),"Active")
```

Note that "irrelevant" can be changed to anything, i.e. 0, etc. This result will never happen, as if VLOOKUP isn't equal to the search cell (in this case, A3), it will throw an error. So, "Active" as the result if there's an error will show rather than the value if VLOOKUP is false (since it can't be).

Hopefully this helps someone!