# Google Sheets match formula only works in certain formulas, but throws error in others

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a large Sheet set that I'm pulling data from into a summary tab. I have some formulas, many of which work, but some which do not, and I can't figure out why. This formula works great:

```
=index(importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$Aj:$aj"),
match($A9&$B9&$C9&$D9&$I9&$N9,importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$A:$a")&
importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$t:$t")&
importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$Ab:$ab")&
importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$b:$b")&
importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$h:$h")&
importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$n:$n"),0),1)
```

Strangely, the "match" portion on its own throws an error (match not found):

```
=match($A9&$B9&$C9&$D9&$I9&$N9,importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$A:$a")&
importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$t:$t")&
importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$Ab:$ab")&
importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$b:$b")&
importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$h:$h")&
importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$n:$n"),0)
```

And the big problem is that this formula throws an error due to the "match" portion:

```
=iferror(if(hlookup(D9&" ROYALTY FINAL",importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$A:$DB"),
match($A9&$B9&$C9&$D9&$I9&$N9,importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$A:$a")&
importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$t:$t")&
importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$Ab:$ab")&
importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$b:$b")&
importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$h:$h")&
importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$n:$n"),0),FALSE)=0,,
hlookup(D9&" ROYALTY FINAL",importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$A:$DB"),
match($A9&$B9&$C9&$D9&$I9&$N9,importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$A:$a")&
importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$t:$t")&
importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$Ab:$ab")&
importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$b:$b")&
importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$h:$h")&
importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$n:$n"),0),FALSE)),)
```

This is a private sheet set (and contains dozens of interlinking sheets), so I can't share it but I have created a sample which reproduces the error (below), but really, the core problem is that "match" works in the index formula, but not on its own, and not within the hlookup formula. I've just copied the match portion around, so I don't see any reason why it wouldn't be working in just certain circumstances. Can anyone see any errors in the formulas? Or any suspicion as to why it won't work?

Incidentally, I also tried importing the data first in a helper tab, and then using this formula (also testing with concatenate):

```
=hlookup(D9&" ROYALTY FINAL",TEMP!$A:$DB,match(concatenate($A9,$B9,$C9,$D9,$I9,$N9),TEMP!$A:$A&TEMP!$T:$T&TEMP!$AB:$AB&TEMP!$B:$B&TEMP!$H:$H&TEMP!$N:$N,0),FALSE)
```

But this still throws the same error...

I've recreated the necessary pieces and the error is here. The sheet with the problem is this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nH144yPYyQZ0r1KYCjiNM8uRjPlS2Ziv6uyWfQrFrcQ/edit?usp=sharing

The errors/samples are on the "COMMISSIONS" tab in columns Y, Z, and AB.

The sheet it imports data from is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kNPtrBhRZxaboIddTM0hGnwJva02hMaKO-67F1FAtUw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi ! Could you please create a sample sheet that can reproduce your issue and share it (making sure it doesn't contain any sensitive data)? Just create a dummy Spreadsheet with the minimum basic features (sheets, data, ranges) to reproduce your problem. Thanks :D

Comment: @MateoRandwolf I've recreated the necessary pieces and the error is here. The sheet with the problem is this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nH144yPYyQZ0r1KYCjiNM8uRjPlS2Ziv6uyWfQrFrcQ/edit?usp=sharing

The errors/samples are on the "COMMISSIONS" tab in columns Y, Z, and AB.

The sheet it imports data from is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kNPtrBhRZxaboIddTM0hGnwJva02hMaKO-67F1FAtUw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: See my possible answer below.  The same solution seems to apply to your HLOOKUP errors.  Just adding ARRAYFORMULA around your existing formula eliminated the error message.  I'll let confirm if it is giving the correct results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one possible answer, but I'm not sure what result you are expecting, so I can't be sure.  If you select cell AB8, in Commissions, which currently shows an error, and do Ctrl-Shift-Enter to make it an arrayformula, that seems to work.  I THINK (not positive) that this is because the concatenation, using the ampersand, is only acting on the first row of your multiple IMPORTRANGE statements.  Test this out by removing the match part of the formula, leaving just:

```
={ 
importrange("1kNPtrBhRZxaboIddTM0hGnwJva02hMaKO-67F1FAtUw","TEAM SALES!$A:$a")&
importrange("1kNPtrBhRZxaboIddTM0hGnwJva02hMaKO-67F1FAtUw","TEAM SALES!$t:$t")&
importrange("1kNPtrBhRZxaboIddTM0hGnwJva02hMaKO-67F1FAtUw","TEAM SALES!$Ab:$ab")&
importrange("1kNPtrBhRZxaboIddTM0hGnwJva02hMaKO-67F1FAtUw","TEAM SALES!$b:$b")&
importrange("1kNPtrBhRZxaboIddTM0hGnwJva02hMaKO-67F1FAtUw","TEAM SALES!$h:$h")&
importrange("1kNPtrBhRZxaboIddTM0hGnwJva02hMaKO-67F1FAtUw","TEAM SALES!$n:$n")}
```

This only returns one row, in my testing.

But adding the ARRAYFORMULA brought back the whole list of properties.

Let me know if this is helpful.  I'll look at the other questions you asked...

**UPDATE:**

If this does work for you, then it can be enhanced as follows, to fill the whole column.  Try this in cell AB8:

```
= ArrayFormula(match($A8:A&$B8:B&$C8:C&$D8:D&$I8:I&$N8:N,
importrange("1kNPtrBhRZxaboIddTM0hGnwJva02hMaKO-67F1FAtUw","TEAM SALES!$A:$A")&
importrange("1kNPtrBhRZxaboIddTM0hGnwJva02hMaKO-67F1FAtUw","TEAM SALES!$t:$t")&
importrange("1kNPtrBhRZxaboIddTM0hGnwJva02hMaKO-67F1FAtUw","TEAM SALES!$Ab:$ab")&
importrange("1kNPtrBhRZxaboIddTM0hGnwJva02hMaKO-67F1FAtUw","TEAM SALES!$b:$b")&
importrange("1kNPtrBhRZxaboIddTM0hGnwJva02hMaKO-67F1FAtUw","TEAM SALES!$h:$h")&
importrange("1kNPtrBhRZxaboIddTM0hGnwJva02hMaKO-67F1FAtUw","TEAM SALES!$n:$n"),0))
```

This can be copied to AB3, once you unmerge that cell.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! I don't know why I didn't think of that, but it was just the arrayformula that was necessary. I'm updating the sheet to the formula that will fill all the columns, so this has also sped things up and lowered memory usage. Just prefect! :)

Answer (score 0):

Before receiving the above perfect answer, I opted for a workaround. I hope this can help someone with similar issues:
The problem seems to be with HLOOKUP (and I assume would be with VLOOKUP as well). I was inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49557844/using-vlookup-and-importrange-to-find-a-match-and-return-one-of-two-potential-va/65006980#65006980), which made me think that HLOOKUP is so quick to throw an error, that it couldn't work through the formula. So, the workaround is to use index/match (matching for both row and column), which is working fine. Here is one of the replaced formulas in case someone has this issue in the future:

```
=iferror(index(importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$A:$DB"),
match($A3&$B3&$C3&$D3&$I3&$N3,importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$A:$a")&
importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$t:$t")&
importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$Ab:$ab")&
importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$b:$b")&
importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$h:$h")&
importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$n:$n"),0),
match(D3&" ROYALTY FINAL",importrange("1HprNdu3RgOimFFkyqp5k3pC79m-YubH0jtT3jKgDxzU","TEAM SALES!$1:$1"),0)),)
```